# Default layout for Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, crud, ejs

I made an API in Sails.js for a user.  I'm in the prototyping phase for a portion of the project and looking to see if there is a way to get a Create/Read/Update/Destroy UI quickly?  Is there a way to generate an EJS file that will do this?  Or do I do it by hand?

This is just for the prototype phase and I'll later clean it all up.  But for testing the functionality of the app it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-admin`](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin).

**Demo**: https://marmelab.com/ng-admin-demo/login.html